# Error while Building Android Source on Ubuntu12.04 in VMware

Tags: android, build, out-of-memory

I have built the android develop environment and downloaded the android4.1-cts source code from the android develop website.But there is an error while building the source code as follows:

```
host Java:ddmlib-tests (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/ddmlib-    tests_intermediates/classes)
host Java: swtmenubar (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/swtmenubar_intermediates/classes)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Vector.<init>(Vector.java:111)
at java.util.Vector.<init>(Vector.java:124)
at org.antlr.analysis.DFA.createTransitionTableEntryForState(DFA.java:551)
at org.antlr.analysis.DFA.createStateTables(DFA.java:440)
at org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.genLookaheadDecision(CodeGenerator.java:645)
at org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.block(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:2876)
at org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.rule(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:2382)
at org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.rules(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:1537)
at org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.grammarSpec(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:1441)
at org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.grammar_(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:461)
at org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.genRecognizer(CodeGenerator.java:421)
at org.antlr.Tool.generateRecognizer(Tool.java:655)
at org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:468)
at org.antlr.Tool.main(Tool.java:93)
make: *** [out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/smali_intermediates/smaliLexer.java] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I have found some solutions, such as changing java -Xms16m -Xmx1024m, but it does not work either.
What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: try one of this http://www.google.com/search?#q=JAVA_LIBRARIES%2Fsmali_intermediates%2FsmaliLexer.java]+Error+1 also don't forget to avoid OpenJDK and use the Java 6 JDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: find the external/smali/smali/android.mk
change add -Xm1024m to $(GEN): PRIVATE_CUSTOM_TOOL = java -jar $(ANTLR_JAR) -fo $(dir $@) $<.

Answer (score 0):

You are having memory issues. Try make -j1 to build the code

Comment: Try this out..as I don't have 4.1 source with me, I can't be sure..   [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-building/Or1C6bpq8) See the last solution..keep me posted